# How to get last N rows of each group in sparklyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, sparklyr

I have a spark data frame with columns id, category, timestamp, price columns. I want to group the data by customer id, category sort by timestamp, and get last n rows in each group.

I tried the below code but it is retuning just 3 rows for overall data. 
`a <- data1 %>% dplyr::group_by(customer_id, category) %>% dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(timestamp)) %>% head(., n = 3)`

please suggest an efficient solution

Answer (score -1):

Without example data we can't know if this will work.

in `Base R`

```
data1 <- data1[order(data1$timestamp),]
lapply(split(data1,data1$customer_ID), tail, n=5)
```

Comment: I can implement in R directly using dplyr::top_n but I want it in sparklyr